# How to insert zeros between elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an nd array, for example this:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

I would like to double the size of the last dimension, and insert zeroes between the elements to fill the space. The result should look like this:

```
[[1,0,2,0,3,0],[4,0,5,0,6,0]]
```

I tried to solve it using `expand_dims` and `pad`. But the `pad` function inserts zeroes not just after each value in the last dimension. The shape of it's result is `(3, 4, 2)`, but it should be `(2,3,2)`

```
y = np.expand_dims(x,-1)
z = np.pad(y, (0,1), 'constant', constant_values=0)
res = np.reshape(z,[-1,2*3]
```

Result of my code:

```
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How is it possible with `pad` to insert zeroes in the last dimension after each element? Or is there any better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply initialize output array and assign with `slicing` -

```
m,n = x.shape
out = np.zeros((m,2*n),dtype=x.dtype)
out[:,::2] = x
```

Alternatively with stacking -

```
np.dstack((x,np.zeros_like(x))).reshape(x.shape[0],-1)
```

Comment: Aargh, I was just writing "There's probably a clever way to do it, but we're Python programmers and so we officially disapprove of being clever.  I'd just build the target array and insert the original one into it," and that's when I saw you'd posted. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with the [insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) function:

```
np.insert(arr=x, obj=[1,2,3], values=0, axis=1)

array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0]])
```

where `obj` are indices *before* which values are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarked some methods I've found:
(1) Sub-index assignment
(2) Stride trick
(3) Padding
(4) Concatenation

```
def dilation1(X, d):
    Xd_shape = np.multiply(X.shape, d)
    Xd = np.zeros(Xd_shape, dtype=X.dtype)
    Xd[0:Xd_shape[0]:d[0], 0:Xd_shape[1]:d[1]] = X
    return Xd

def dilation2(X, d):
    Xd_shape = np.multiply(X.shape, d)
    Xd = np.zeros(Xd_shape, dtype=X.dtype)
    Xdn = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(Xd, X.shape, np.multiply(Xd.strides, d))
    Xdn[:] = X
    return Xd

def dilation3(X, d):
    Xd = X.reshape((X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1],1))
    Xd = np.pad(Xd, ((0,0),(0,d[0]-1),(0,0),(0,d[1]-1)))
    return Xd.reshape(np.multiply(X.shape,d))

def dilation4(X, d):
    Xd = X.reshape((X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1],1))
    mcol = np.zeros(Xd.shape[:3]+(d[1]-1,))
    Xd = np.concatenate((Xd, mcol), 3)
    mrow = np.zeros((Xd.shape[0],d[0]-1)+Xd.shape[2:])
    Xd = np.concatenate((Xd, mrow), 1)
    return Xd.reshape(np.multiply(X.shape,d))

#Example
b = np.arange(3*3).reshape((3,3))
b
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])
dilation1(b, (3,2))
# array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

#Benchmark
a = np.random.randn(1024,1024)

%timeit -r 20 dilation1(a, (5,5))
#19.7 ms ± 890 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -r 20 dilation2(a, (5,5))
#18.8 ms ± 526 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -r 20 dilation3(a, (5,5))
#101 ms ± 2.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -r 20 dilation4(a, (5,5))
#101 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So simply use the sub-index assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of your expand_dims, we can use `stack`:

```
In [742]: x=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,-1)
In [743]: x
Out[743]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [744]: np.stack([x,x*0],axis=-1).reshape(2,-1)
Out[744]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0]])
```

`stack` uses `expend_dims` to add a dimension; it's like `np.array` but with more control over how the new axis is added.  Thus it is a handy way of interspersing arrays.

The stack produces a (2,4,2) array which we reshape to (2,8).

`x*0` could be replaced with `np.zeros_like(x)`, or anything that creates the same size of zero array.

`np.stack([x,x*0],axis=1).reshape(4,-1)` to add 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to [pad only one side](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) of the new dimension:

```
x = np.array( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] )
y = np.expand_dims(x,-1)
z = np.pad( y, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)) , 'constant', constant_values=0)
res = np.reshape(z, ( x.shape[0] , 2*x.shape[1] ) )
                 
res
```

> ```
> array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
>        [4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0]])
> ```