# Inserting multiple elements in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there a function in python that allows me to insert number 100's  or consecutive non zeros in the array [1,2,3,4,5]?

Output should be [1, 100, 100, 100, 2, 100, 100, 100, 3 .....] or [ 1, 100, 101, 102, 2 , 100, 101, 102, 3...]

I have tried numpy.insert()

ar2=np.insert(ar1, slice(1,None), range(100,103))

Output: array([  1, 100,   2, 101,   3, 102,   4, 100,   5, 101])

Numpy.Insert() method allows addition of only a single number between the input elements. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: The ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125884/how-to-insert-zeros-between-elements-in-a-numpy-array for single 0s between numbers could be generalized to insert multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.kron`

```
np.kron([1,2,3,4,5],[1,0,0,0]) + 100*np.kron(np.ones(5),[0,1,1,1])
```

for the second one

```
np.kron([1,2,3,4,5],[1,0,0,0]) + np.kron(np.ones(5),[0,101,102,103])
```